# Change websites language with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to web scraping amazon with python and selenium, but I need to translate the page to English first.

this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.set_headless(True)
w = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
  "translate_whitelists": {"es":"en"},
  "translate":{"enabled":"true"}
}
w.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=f"{getcwd()}\chromedriver.exe")

url = str(input("type amazon url: "))

driver.get(url)
```

the page is in Spanish, I saw this solution with "add_experimental_option" here, but it doesn't work, the page still in Spanish.

Comment: `input` is automatically converted to a string so you don't need `str` around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your solution is correct , if its not working add the --lang=en argument

so it means your chrome browser didn't had english langugae pack installed so using --lang=en will use chrome language as english . and using es:en will ensure all spanish words are translated to english for which we installed langugae pack using --lang=en

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--lang=en");
prefs = {
  "translate_whitelists": {"es":"en"},
  "translate":{"enabled":"true"}
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

url = "https://www.amazon.es/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the options into the webdriver.chrome.

```
options = Options()
prefs = {
  "translate_whitelists": {"es":"en"},
  "translate":{"enabled":"true"}
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=f"{getcwd()}\chromedriver.exe",options=options)
```